# IoT Hub SAS Tokens Node JS Crypto error

Tags: azure, cryptography, azure-iot-hub

I have a problem when using SAS tokens to connect with IoT Hub.
In the example from Microsoft, there is an example code for NodeJS to create a SAS token with crypto. However, when I use this code in NodeJS, it throws  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTvmA.png) error.

However, I did everything in the tutorial and I cannot see anything missing.
The example code is the following:

```
// Creating SAS token
var crypto = require('crypto');

var generateSasToken = function (resourceUri, signingKey, policyName, expiresInMins) {
    resourceUri = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase();

    // Set expiration in seconds
    var expires = (Date.now() / 1000) + expiresInMins * 60;
    expires = Math.ceil(expires);
    var toSign = resourceUri + '\n' + expires;

    // using crypto
    var decodedPassword = new Buffer(signingKey, 'base64').toString('binary');
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', decodedPassword);
    hmac.update(toSign);
    var base64signature = hmac.digest('base64');
    var base64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(base64signature);

    // construct autorization string
    var token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + resourceUri + "&sig=" 
    * base64UriEncoded + "&se=" + expires;
    if (policyName) token += "&skn=" + policyName;
     console.log("signature:" + token);
    return token;
};
```

I hope that someone can help me with this mystery haha..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that shows in your screenshot indicates that a part of the shared access signature is missing or cannot be parsed.

there are a couple things I can see in your code:

1. when concatenating the string to create the token there's a `*` that should be a `+`
2. the way you generate the hmac hash: we don't use 'toString('binary') on the base64 encoded buffer containing the password (shouldn't be an issue with node, will be an issue if you're trying to use browserify):

```js
function hmacHash(password, stringToSign) {
  var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(password, 'base64'));
  hmac.update(stringToSign);
  return hmac.digest('base64');
}
```

(reference: [authorization.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/common/core/lib/authorization.js#L35))

From the screenshot of the error it looks like you're already using the node.js SDK, have you tried using the `SharedAccessSignature.create(...)` method of either the [Device SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/device/core/lib/shared_access_signature.js#L10) or the [Service SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/service/lib/shared_access_signature.js#L9) (depending on what you're trying to achieve?)

it would replace the code you posted by:

```js
// compute expiry value
var expires = (Date.now() / 1000) + expiresInMins * 60;
expires = Math.ceil(expires);
// generate SAS token
var sas = SharedAccessSignature.create(resourceUri, policyName, signingKey, expires);
// from then you can create a client object:
var client = Client.fromSharedAccessSignature(sas.toString());
```